# Angular: load SQL data into textbox

Tags: javascript, html, sql, angular

I have a mat-table where its data is loaded from database, one of the columns must be a textbook so the user can edit its content to update the table in the database

the problem is that I can't load the data in the textbox

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="test">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> test </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><input type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="model.test" 
        name="test"  id="test" >{{row.test}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

how to make the data `{{row.test}}` inside the textbox ?

Comment: Can you show your component code? Angular directly cant talk to database, you have to call some api and api will talk to db.

Answer (score 1):

For that I would recommend you use the value property like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{row.test}}" [(ngModel)]="model.test" name="test"  id="test" >
```

This way you will have the default value *row.test* in your input and it will still bind to *model.test* for your model. For more information about user input you can read the official [input docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).

Comment: Could you add your component code to your question? It will be easier to help you!